# Find linear transformation without factoring its characteristic polynomial (if given)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Find a linear transformation $\text{T}: \mathbb{R^5}\to \mathbb{R^5}$ whose characteristic polynomial is $p(t)=-(t^5-3t^3+t)$ **without factoring** $p(t)$.

Does it have anything to do with canonical forms? I have been stuck on this problem for quite a while, and haven't yet figured out why we need not factor the characteristic polynomial. Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: A look at this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix will be useful.

Comment: Thank, but I think to compute companion matrices we do need factor the characteristic polynomial in order to get monic polynomials. Is it necessary?

Comment: @LiebsterJugendtraum you don't need to factor the polynomial, you just need to multiply it by $-1$.